# Could I ask how do I know how many pages are in the website? (Web scrapping)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I get a website (https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/)

And I found there are many forum pages
[image]

Want to use the for loop for web scrapping, therefore could I ask, how I get the maximum number of forum pages on this page by BeaurifulSoup?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.content, 'html.parser')
navs = soup.find("ul", { "class" : "pageNav-main" }).find_all("li", recursive=False)
print(navs)
print(f'Length: {len(navs)}')
```

**Result**

```
[<li class="pageNav-page pageNav-page--current"><a href="/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/">1</a></li>, <li class="pageNav-page pageNav-page--later"><a href="/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/page-2">2</a></li>, <li class="pageNav-page pageNav-page--later"><a href="/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/page-3">3</a></li>, <li class="pageNav-page"><a href="/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/page-4">4</a></li>]
Length: 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could I ask why cannot find the link by "a href" but it can be found by "li"? Also could ask why recursive is used?

Comment: If you want to get the `href`, you have to loop through `navs` and do this `print(navs[idx].find('a')['href'])`

Comment: Oh, thanks, why when I see the link in web code that writes <a href>, but in many cases, I cannot just get its link by using find_all for a?

Comment: `find_all()` will return a list of `<a>`. Therefore, to get the `href`, you have to loop through the list first, then do `['href']`. You can however get only only one `<a>` using `find()['href']`, but it will get you the very first `<a>` element in the page. So, you need the "key" element of your target, which in your case is `<ul>` that has a class pageNav-main``. From here, you can get the children of `<li>` to count max number of the page.

Comment: If, let's say, you want to get a specific `href` from `<a>`, you need some kind of element ID or unique class, then do `find('a', class_"className")['href']` or `find('a', {'id': 'idElement'})['href']`

Comment: Oh, I see, then I need to pay attention to these issues for future web scrapping. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. Encourage yourself to read the documentation, because there's more to find there. Good luck!

Comment: thank you! maybe I can work hard on it later.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need BeautifulSoup to count the number of pages.

URL of page 1 : `https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/page-1`

URL of page 2 : `https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/page-2`

URL of page 3 : `https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/page-3`

And so on...

So you need to increment the value `X` in `https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/page-X` to move to the next page. You can then check the status code of the response and the page title to ensure that we are not visiting the same page twice.

```py
import requests
import re


def getPageTitle(response_text):
    d = re.search('<\W*title\W*(.*)</title', response_text, re.IGNORECASE)
    return d.group(1)


def count_pages():
    count = 0
    uniquePages = set()
    while(True):
        count += 1
        url = ('https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/' +
               f'had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/page-{count}')
        response = requests.get(url)
        title = getPageTitle(response.text)
        if title in uniquePages or response.status_code != 200:
            break
        uniquePages.add(title)
    return len(uniquePages)


print(count_pages())  # 4
```

Comment: Could ask how do you aware 'https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/page-1' also works? Because when I copying the website , I just found 'https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/'

Comment: I mean I don't find 'page-1' when I investigating the website.

Comment: `page-1` redirects you to the original webpage even though there's no actual `page-1` in the URL. So you can say `page-1` exists. Also if you try `page-999` or any other numbers greater than 4 you will be redirected to `page-4`. That's why it's important to keep track of the already visited webpages or otherwise we will end up in an infinite loop.